# Value of variable changes when accessed out of closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I wrote the following code, when accessed out of closure the value of the variable "total" changes back to the initialised value i.e 4

```
func getTotal() -> Int{

   let task = totalDB.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
            let jsonData = JSON(data)

            print("\n\n\n\n",jsonData,"\n\n\n\n\n")
            print(self.total,"\n\n")
            self.total=jsonData["Total"].intValue

        }
    }

return total

}
```

I initialised the variable :

```
    var total:Int = 4
```

Comment: Your logic is a bit strange. I think that you are misunderstanding something on a conceptual level. Where is `getTotal()` called? You are both setting `self.total` and returning total... Perhaps you want to remove the return? I would also then rename the method to something like `setTotalFromDB()`. And then why do you have both a getTotal and total? Perhaps the getTotal should live in a different place instead? Then usually one would pass in an escaping closure here instead.

Comment: getTotal() is called in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking why the value returned by getTotal() might be different than what it should be according to the closure, this is almost certainly because the function is returning *before* the code in the closure is executing. You can confirm this in Xcode by setting a breakpoint on the `self.total=jsonData...` line and another on the `return total` line and see which breakpoint is hit first.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with a completion handler.

```
func getTotal(_ completion: @escaping(_ error: Error?, _ value: Int?) -> Void) {
       let task = totalDB.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            if let data = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                let jsonData = JSON(data)

                print("\n\n\n\n",jsonData,"\n\n\n\n\n")
                print(self.total,"\n\n")
                completion(nil,jsonData["Total"].intValue)

            } else { completion(NSError(domain: "Data not found", code: 0, userInfo: nil),nil) }
        }
    }
```

This bit of code above will get the total value and pass it through the handler. Then you can access it when you call the `getTotal()` function. If you get an error output you'll know that you are improperly accessing the snapshot.

Below is an example of how to use the new function:

```
....

// wherever you need the int value
var myNum = 0

getTotal({ (error, num) in 
    if error != nil { 
        print("error getting data", error!.localizedDescription) 
    } else { 
        myNum = num // do what you want here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have return value from asynchronous function/closure. In your case `totalDB.observe(.value)` will execute passed closure asynchronously and your return statement is synchronous statement, so return statement will be executed even before your closure gets executed.

What you need is a completion block

```
func getTotal(@escaping completionBlock : ((Int) -> ())) {
        let task = totalDB.observe(.value) {[weak self] (snapshot) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }

            if let data = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                let jsonData = JSON(data)
                print("\n\n\n\n",jsonData,"\n\n\n\n\n")
                print(strongSelf.total,"\n\n")
                strongSelf.total=jsonData["Total"].intValue
                completionBlock(strongSelf.total)
            }
        }

    }
```

Finally you can call it as

```
    self.getTotal() {[weak self] value in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }
        debugPrint("do whatever you wanna do with total here")
    }
```

It is not advised to pass strong self to closure, passing weak/unowned self and using guard let get safer access to self will make sure you will not end up in retain cycle/crash because of self not available

Hope this helps